Two gang cover - half receptacle half flat?
I am planning out a rewire of my basement to add more light. Once I run the main power wire (14-2) from the main panel and through the switch I need to split it into two branches for the two sides of my basement in order to apply power to the outlets that will take the lights' plugs.
Due to the layout relationships of the switch, plumbing, furnace, and joists there is a particular spot on the ceiling that would work great as BOTH a receptacle for lights AND a spot to put the splice that will split the main wire to the two branches.
I have, so far, been unable to find a 2-gang box cover where one side has holes for a standard electric receptacle and the other side has no holes (so one side of the box would have the recruitable and the other would hold the splice).
Does such a box cover exist? Or do I have to use one box to splice the power three ways (one to a different box for the receptacle, one to the west branch of outlets, one to the east branch of outlets)?

These are actually fairly common. Search "2 gang single switch decora cover plate". VTC as a shopping question.

Are you using a metal j-box, or a plastic one?

First of all, you can find pretty much any type of combination if you look hard enough. For example, here is a Leviton Decora/blank from Home Depot:

and here is one with a traditional duplex/blank:

In addition, you may be able to use a large metal box - e.g., 4" (or larger) square - with a cover plate that is designed for a single device. I have one right in front of me that my electrician installed (I think) in 2006 with a GFCI/receptacle. Something like this Southwire:

So if you already have the 2-gang boxes in place with the receptacles on one side, go with matching plates. If you are still gathering all the pieces, go with metal boxes and metal cover plates and you'll have plenty of room (both in reality and to satisfy code box fill requirements) to do your splicing in the box.

Just for completeness, you can also get a ‘decora blank insert’, or probably fit two receptacles.

Possibly you could use a deeper single gang box and have the splice at the back and the outlet at the front.  at the end of the day it's all cubic inches and so long as you have enough of them and enough ins and outs you're golden.
